# Can I run git-bisect using the reflog?

Tags: git

I have a test file that was destroyed somewhere in a rebase.

I used `git-bisect` to find that one commit it is 0 bytes and in the prior commit it doesn't exist. But at some point in the last few weeks this file was 8kb. This branch has seen a lot of rebases lately, so it must have been destroyed in a rebase.

Is there a way to use `git-bisect` **on a branch's reflog** to find the last known good state of the file?

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need `git bisect` for this. Just iterate over the reflog in reverse chronological order and find the first commit in which your file is > 0 bytes.

Comment: @larsks true, and I **did** iterate manually; but it occurred to me that it could have been done faster if there were a `bisect`-like command that worked on the reflog

Comment: `git bisect` can't help here. You have to do the bisection manually.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer: no

As of January 2024 (latest release is Git 2.43.0), there is no automatic way of doing this. Of course, it is possible to manually bisect reflog entries using `@{1}`, `@{2}`, `@{3}`, etc and `@{1 week ago}` syntaxes. More info in `git help gitrevisions`, also [available online](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emem).

#### Long answer / Why not?

While a reflog can be viewed as a list of commits, `git bisect` works only on *linked* lists of commits. That is, the commits under consideration have to be connected together via parent links (most commits have one, merge commits usually have two, root commit has zero). This is often described using the word "reachable" in the documentation, e.g. for [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the given commit(s), [...]

[Documentation for `git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) doesn't spell it out, calling the search space "project's history":

> This command uses a binary search algorithm to find which commit in your project’s history introduced a bug. You use it by first telling it a "bad" commit that is known to contain the bug, and a "good" commit that is known to be before the bug was introduced. Then `git bisect` picks a commit between those two endpoints and asks you whether the selected commit is "good" or "bad".

The phrase "picks a commit between those two endpoints" means that the picked commit is reachable from one of the endpoints, while the other endpoint is reachable from the picked commit.